# How to extract both ZIP and RAR archives using 7-Zip command?

Tags: cmd, zip, 7zip, rar

Using 7-Zip command line it's easy to extract either RAR or ZIP archives. The following code is for extracting ZIP archives:

```
7z x *.zip -r
```

How to recode it so that it will work for both ZIP and RAR archives (or other additional archives that I can add based on my preference)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cmd window

```
For %A in (zip rar) do 7z.exe x -r *.%A
```

In a batch file

```
For %%A in (zip rar) do 7z.exe x -r *.%%A
```